# Creating new user in Active Directory and setting the samAccountName gives a weird string

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am to create a user. I auto generate a username through a function.

Then I do:

```
MessageBox.Show(userName);
user.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = userName;
```

I use the message box to ensure that the `userName` value is as expected. It is.
The format is something like XBeBoReso as an example. However once the user is created and I check manually on Active Directory the samAccountName is something like:
$AM2000-JDU226IQG9UL

Why does this occur? I can't seem to find where this change is made.

Comment: You auto generate a username through a function (how-to), but you must validate it in AD, that not exists

Answer (score 0):

$AM2000-JDU226IQG9UL is an autogenerated logon name. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675773(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The server will create a random sAMAccountName value if none is
>   specified.

This could mean, that AD didn't get the value and you need to check one more time if your code really takes and saves the correct value. I would also try to change `samAccountName` to `sAMAccountName` to check if it would make any difference.

Comment: I solved this by committing the changes to the user and then reset the samAccountName value again. That did the trick.

Comment: How-to generate available sAMAccountName? Cannot exists in AD, must be ***new***